# Execute command while starting qtconsole

Tags: python, ipython

This command:

`ipython -c "x = 'hello'" -i`

starts interactive IPython shell and executes the command so I have the `x` variable in session namespace.

But this command:

`ipython qtconsole -c "x = 'hello'" -i`

prints IPython help screen, indicating error in arguments.

How to execute oneliner while starting interactive IPython qtconsole session?